# Управление памятью в C#

Tags: c#, производительность, memory

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли вручную управлять памятью в C#? Например удалять объекты когда тебе это необходимо, а не когда заблагорассудится сборщику мусора.

Comment: Если вам такое нужно, есть большие шансы, что вы что-то делаете неправильно. Необходимость детерминистического освобождения памяти возникает очень нечасто: обычно это либо обладание важным разделяемым ресурсом (файл, блокировка), либо очень большой объект в памяти (обработка картинок). В обоих случаях вполне достаточно `IDisposable` плюс возможный ручной запуск `GC.Collect`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Можно](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx), но в ограниченных пределах, а вообще не нужно. Если используете классы, реализующие `IDisposable`, не забывайте про `Dispose()` (либо про конструкцию `using`)

Comment: а оверхед на маршалинг большой получается?

Comment: Зависит от ваших ожиданий. Проведённые вами тесты уже показали, что узким местом является сборщик мусора?

Comment: я просто читал статью (раздел "Нехватка памяти") http://www.rsdn.ru/article/dotnet/GC.xml , на с++ тест занял 2 секунды, а на C# аж 20 минут, неужели все так печально?

Comment: @Merlin, нужно использовать правильные средства для правильных целей. Если вы столкнулись с описанной в статье ситуацией (заняли практически всю свободную память), то вам, скорее всего, придётся пользоваться неуправляемой кучей.

Answer (score 4):

Я перечитал [статью](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/dotnet/GC.xml), на которую указывает ТС. Статья датирована 2006-м годом, с тех времён алгоритмы сборки мусора сильно изменились. Я скомпилировал и запустил проекты на тестовой 32-битной машине.

(Заметьте, что на 64-битной машине гораздо больше доступного адресного пространства, и сборщик мусора будет работать гораздо меньше. У кого под рукой 64-битная машина, проверьте, пожалуйста, сравните и отпишитесь!)

---

C++: 
В исходниках исправил 10000 на `PermanentObjectsCount` в строке 102, была явная ошибка.
Скомпилировал Release, запуск с командной строки 5 раз, с разными опциями.

Параметры теста: 
`PermanentObjectsCount`: количество «мёртвых» объектов, которые лишь занимают память и мешают алгоритмам аллокации

`QUICK_HEAP_OPERATOR_NEW`: макрос, подключающий кастомный аллокатор памяти

Результаты:

> `PermanentObjectsCount` = 1, `QUICK_HEAP_OPERATOR_NEW` включено:
> Timestamp: 2.332243/2.285392/2.310033/2.329071/2.362159, среднее 2,3237796
> ObjCount=10001001
>
> `PermanentObjectsCount` = 1, `QUICK_HEAP_OPERATOR_NEW` выключено
> Timestamp: 3.123940/3.130930/3.113295/3.139964/3.104077, среднее 3.1224412
> ObjCount=10001001
>
> `PermanentObjectsCount` = 10 * 1000 * 1000, `QUICK_HEAP_OPERATOR_NEW` включено:
> Timestamp: 7.175451/7.234413/7.241763/7.197331/7.226205, среднее 7.2150326
> ObjCount=20001000
>
> `PermanentObjectsCount` = 10 * 1000 * 1000, `QUICK_HEAP_OPERATOR_NEW` выключено:
> Timestamp: 8.823886/8.751605/8.908837/8.825099/8.806487, среднее 8.8231828
> ObjCount=20001000

---

Теперь C#:

Переконфигурировал проект на использования .NET 4.5. Скомпилировал Release, запуск с командной строки 5 раз, с разными опциями.

Параметры теста:

`PermanentObjectsCount`: количество «мёртвых» объектов, которые лишь занимают память и мешают сборщику мусора

Установки сборщика мусора в `app.config` по умолчанию (`<gcConcurrent enabled="false"/>` отключено):

> `PermanentObjectsCount` = 1
> 00:00:01.6406347/1.5898657/1.6479692/1.6528195/1.5796367, среднее 1.62218516
> Количество созданных объектов: 10001001
> Количество сборок мусора поколения 0: 571
> Количество сборок мусора поколения 1: 145
> Количество сборок мусора поколения 2: 3
>
> `PermanentObjectsCount` = 10 * 1000 * 1000
> 00:00:15.5065372/16.4615645/16.5447826/15.4274263/16.3169154, среднее 16.0514452
> Количество созданных объектов: 20001000
> Количество сборок мусора поколения 0: 758
> Количество сборок мусора поколения 1: 256
> Количество сборок мусора поколения 2: 10

Запросил серверный сборщик мусора в `app.config` (`<gcServer enabled="true"/>`):

> `PermanentObjectsCount` = 1
> 00:00:01.9130864/1.8731294/1.8649931/1.6231794/1.8787851, среднее 1.83063468
> Количество созданных объектов: 10001001
> Количество сборок мусора поколения 0: 243
> Количество сборок мусора поколения 1: 43
> Количество сборок мусора поколения 2: 3
>
> `PermanentObjectsCount` = 10 * 1000 * 1000
> 00:00:14.2030724/13.8427775/14.0393846/14.5345637/14.2312238, среднее 14.1702044
> Количество созданных объектов: 20001000
> Количество сборок мусора поколения 0: 249
> Количество сборок мусора поколения 1: 54
> Количество сборок мусора поколения 2: 5

---

Выводы:

Сборщик мусора тогда и сборщик мусора сейчас — разные вещи.

- В довольно редком для реальных программ случае наличия 10 миллионов статических объектов сборщик мусора .NET существенно ускорился, и теперь отстаёт от нативного аллокатора не в 86 раз, а всего вдвое. Серверный аллокатор немного лучше справляется с нагрузкой.
- В случае, когда работа управления памятью не затруднена, аллокатор .NET выигрывает более чем в полтора раза.

Кастомный аллокатор для нативного кода ускоряет работу, но я бы не стал использовать непроверенный аллокатор в серьёзном коде: был бы он лучше встроенного в C++, уж разработчики компилятора без сомнений заменили бы свой аллокатор на этот.

Comment: Сколько свободной памяти было в вашей системе во время теста?

Comment: @Flammable: пробовал и с пустой памятью, и с загруженной (2 экземпляра Visual Studio, MS Word + MS Excel, Paint.NET и 50 больших картинок, VirtualBox). Результаты отличаются незначительно.

---
Впрочем, здесь мы уже переходим к разговору о производительности подсистемы виртуальной памяти. На машине, где происходили измерения, быстрый винт. Система — 32-битная Windows 7.

Comment: @VladD, падение производительности GC в тесте было сопряжено с ~90% загрузкой памяти. Насколько я понял, в вашем случае свободной памяти было достаточно для того, чтобы GC не причесывал кучу слишком часто.

Comment: @Flammable: Вряд ли. Process Explorer показывал почти полную загрузку памяти. Количество проходов сборки мусора 0-го поколения, кстати, различается не так уж и сильно. Меньшее количество для старших поколений вполне объясняется возросшим качеством GC и улучшенным jit-оптимизатором.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы работаете с  COM объектами, то им нужно вызывать метод Marshal.ReleaseComObject